# Passport.js Facebook Strategy not working because URL Blocked

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, facebook-authentication

I'm getting this error when I go to localhost:3000 and use the login with facebook button.

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

Even when I'm not logged in on facebook, and I try to get directed to facebook for login, I get a blank page with this error instead

> Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.

Here's my auth module's index.js:

```
'use strict';
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../config');
const h = require('../helpers');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

module.exports = () => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        //Find the user using the _id
        h.findById(id)
            .then(user => done(null, user))
            .catch(error => console.log('Error when deserializing user'));
    });

    let authProcessor = (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // Find a user in the local db using profile.id
        // If the user is found, return the user data using the done() method
        // If the user is not found, create one in the local db and return
        h.findOne(profile.id)
            .then(result => {
                if(result) {
                    done(null, result);
                } else {
                    // Create a new user and return
                    h.createNewUser(profile)
                        .then(newChatUser => done(null, newChatUser))
                        .catch(error => console.log("Error when creating a new user"))
                }
            })
    }
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(config.fb, authProcessor));
```

Here's my config / development.json file. I took out the values of dbURI and fb clientID & secret, but in my development, those values do exist and were obtained from their respective providers.

```
{
    "host": "http://localhost:3000",
    "dbURI": "",
    "sessionSecret": "catscanfly",
    "fb": {
        "clientID": "",
        "clientSecret": "",
        "calbackURL": "//localhost:3000/auth/facbeook/callback",
        "profileFields": ["id", "displayName", "photos"]
    }
}
```

[Whole app on github](https://github.com/RoadToCode822/catchat)

Answer (score 0):

this line here:
"calbackURL": "//localhost:3000/auth/facbeook/callback"

Check to see what site your fb app is configured for.
I modified my hosts file to use local.mysite.com:3000 and FB accepted that.

Edit:
Did you resolve the issue?